# Export Mysql data to a customized XLS file using php

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel

First of all, I do know the process of exporting MySQL data to excel file using php. But I have some specific requirement and I want to know if it can be done or not. I have already googled, but didn't get any specific information or method regarding the same.

**This is my xls template :**

[image]

**Overview:**

Column C is fixed and others are scrollable.
There are basically couple of organizations.

Data starting from COL-C8 to COL-L8 is exactly stored on a MySQL Table of an organization (e.g. Organization1).

Data of COL-C1 to COL-C5 & D1 to D5 is on another MySQL Table of Organization1.

So for every organization there are 2 different MySQL tables.

**Requirement :**

The goal is to export data from MySQL and add it to the excel file according to the image above.

**Problem :**

Adding data from MySQL table to excel is pretty easy if the requirement is to just replicate same on the excel sheet. But I have no idea how to do this customization.

Like pulling data from two different tables and adding them to different columns in an excel sheet.

Please let me know if it is possible. And if yes, then kindly direct me to some references on how to achieve this.

Thank You!

Comment: What did you try so far? @Peejay

Comment: So are you having problems formulating an SQL query that references two tables? If so, then have you looked at using JOINS?

Comment: As mentioned... I can get the data exactly from one mysql table...but do not know the process of adding data from two table as shown on the image reference. @Testing

Comment: I am actually having two problems
1. do not know the process of adding data from two tables as required on the xls.
2. how to fix a column of that xls file using php

Comment: The process to retrieve data from two tables starts with writing a database query (or queries).... show your actual database table structures (including relationships between them) and the columns that you need from each, and we might be able to help write the query for you

Comment: I followed your code on the discussions page of phpexcel and achieved to get the data from a table to excel file. Now I want to add data from other tables also to the same excel side-by-side. the tables are not fixed and will increase in number going forward...but the columns name will always be same. Can you help me on that please.... @MarkBaker

Comment: Without knowing anything about your tables, or the queries that you want to run, it's almost impossible to help you with that

Comment: tell me where can I show you the tables and my code?

Comment: @MarkBaker...Can you please help me with this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588757/export-mysql-data-from-two-tables-to-excel-using-php-and-phpexcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). This library allows you to read and write from/to .xls files.

Comment: It seems like a relevant solution...but I don;t know if it can serve all my purposes... like adding data from two different tables and freeze a column in xls or csv

Comment: PHPExcel is perfectly capable of freezing a column or setting your colour styles for xls or xlsx files, it simply isn't possible in a csv file that has no concept of format or structure.... but it won't write a database query for you..... it's up to you to write the database query to get the data that you want to put in the spreadsheet